# Comparing computational and analytic results of linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

Consider simple one feature linear regression. x = features, w = weights
We have w for the best fit to the linear regression model as,
w = (xTx)^(-1)xTy
Now I am comparing results I got from scikit learn regressor and computational w method and they have significant difference among them.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
x = data.iloc[:,[0]].values
y = data.iloc[:,[1]].values
#space
x_t = np.transpose(x)
first_inv = np.matmul(x_t, x)
second = np.matmul(x_t, y)
first = np.linalg.inv(first_inv)
theta = np.matmul(first, second)
y_prad = theta*x
#space
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x, y)
y_prad2 = regressor.predict(x)
#space
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_prad , 'red')
plt.plot(x, y_prad2, 'green')
```

[image: refer the graph for the difference]

Where am I wrong here?(whatever in concepts or code)

Comment: Can you please write code instead of image. It is easier for others to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the intercept term. Add a column of ones to the x matrix using
`np.insert(x, 0, 1, axis=1)`
 and then re-run the calculations. The shape of x should be (30, 2) where the first column is all 1's to represent the constant multiplied by the intercept. The final shape of theta should be (2, 1) where the first term is the intercept and the second is the slope.

Here is a good reference for matrix formulation of linear regression.
[Matrix Formulation of Linear Regression](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/382)